# Injected HttpServletRequest in UserDetailsService isn't the wrapped HttpServletRequest added by filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

How can i put my custom filter, that wraps the `HttpServletRequest` using `HttpServletRequestWrapper`, so that the `HttpServletRequest` that is `@Autowired` in my custom `UserDetailsService`, so that it sees the wrapped `HttpServletRequest` instead of a normal `HttpServletRequest` ?

Let me try to explain: in my custom filter i analyze the subdomain and domain and put handy information in the `HttpServletRequest` by wrapping it with `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and overriding `getHeader()`.

But when i inject a `HttpServletRequest` using `@Autowired` in `UserDetailsService` the injected `HttpServletRequest` is not the Wrapped one and doesn't contain the information added by my custom filter.

In my `web.xml` i have put my filter first before all the spring filters (`ContextLoaderListener`, `RequestContextListener` and `DelegatingFilterProxy`), so my filter should be first inline. It does make me wonder.

Note that when i inject the `HttpServletRequest` in a normal controller it injects the wrapped `HttpServletRequest`. `UserDetailsService` might be a special case.

Anyone got a bright idea?

Comment: How do you expose `HttpServletRequest`? Show your web.xml.

Comment: @dur my web.xml contains the filters and the standard spring stuff every spring app has. And spring exposes the HttpServletRequest, i simply inject with Autowired. Note that, as pointed out in my post, the injection is working as expected in normal controllers but not in UserDetailsService, leading me to think that configuration wise everything is ok but UserDetailsService is a special case. But i can't find much related to HttpServletRequestWrapper and UserDetailsService.

Comment: There are three ways to expose the `HttpServletRequest`. You have to use the right way. Show your web.xml.

Comment: Don't do things like that. Your `UserDetailsService` shouldn't know anything about the fact it is running inside a web application. What you should do instead is put so called details inside your `Authentication` which contain the additional information you need. See the `UsernamaPasswordFilter` which uses a default `WebAuthenticationDetails` to pass stuff around, you can create your own `AuthenticationDetailsSource` and fill your own details object with the required information.

Comment: Cheers @M.Deinum , i gave it a shot, but Authentication (used for auth.getDetails()) is always null in my loadUserByUsername in UserDetailsService, which makes sense because user is not authenticated yet. Although i see that MyWebAuthenticationDetails is called before loadUserByUsername, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the WebAuthenticationDetails in loadUserByUsername?

Comment: It should be part of the passed in `Authentication` if it isn't you are doing weird things in your flow.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks, UserDetailsService doesn't have access to the Authentication, it is a interface with 1 function loadUserByUsername. I also did try to get it from SecurityContextHolder but that one is null. Looking a bit further is it possible that i need to implement a custom AuthenticationProvider which has access to Authentication as parameter of the authenticate method.

Comment: My bad. Was thinking on a higher level with the `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. What is it you need/want to do with the additional information (generally you shouldn't be doing that in your `UserDetailsService` in the first place but really in your`AuthenticationProvider` or by extending Spring security using the callback interfaces.

Comment: Cheers @M.Deinum , i'm going to give a custom AuthenticationProvider a try.

Comment: You shouldn't need one, what is the use case you are trying to implementment?

Comment: Its quite complicated, but a small part is that which user database i pick depends on the subdomain/domain in the request and which subdomain/domain is only known at run time and can change. Because my filter already puts the handy information in the HttpServletRequestWrapper for custom requestmapping's and such my thought was i could also use it for authentication. Note as a temp. solution i now put specific information in a request attribute which my UserDetailsService can read. Bit hacky and duplication of data i admit. I'll post a answer soon. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the HttpServletRequest injected in UserDetailsService differs from normal controllers.

In normal controllers a request.getHeader call results in a call to the wrapped request.getHeader. In UserDetailsService this doesn't seem to be the case. I suspect the HttpServletRequest in UserDetailsService is a copy and doesn't wrap/proxy around the original HttpServletRequest, maybe it needs to be serialized.

But lucky one can use request.setAttribute, request attributes are available in the injected HttpServletRequest in UserDetailsService and normal controllers.

Note that above is a bit hacky. Depending on your use case you might want to read the interesting comments of @M. Deinum and go the AuthenticationProvider route with data in a custom WebAuthenticationDetails that is generated by a custom AuthenticationDetailsSource.